# Show that a nonempty set of integers that is closed under subtraction must also be closed under addition

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

So this is what I have so far:

Let X be a nonempty set of integers

Let $a,b\in X$ and we need to show that $a+b\in X$

Because $b\in X$ and X is closed under subtraction, than $b-b\in X$

Once again, by closure under subtraction $b-(b-b)\in X$

Since $a\in X$ as well, by closure under subtraction, $a-[(b-b)-b]\in X$

$a-[(b-b)-b]=a-(b-2b)=a-(-b)=a+b$

$\therefore a+b\in X$

But how would I show that the empty set is closed under addition as well?

Comment: It is trivially closed under addition. We want to show the sum of any two elements of the set is in the set. If the set is empty, there are no elements in the set. (You were not asked this question.)

Comment: This is a special case of the [subgroup test.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test) The set X is also closed under remainder (mod), and gcd, so $\rm\, X = n\Bbb Z,\,$ for $\rm\: n = $ least positive element or, equivalently $\rm\,n = gcd\, X.$

Comment: Why are you considering the empty set when you have as hypothesis that X is nonempty?

Answer (score 4):

It would help readability of your argument if you said something like this:

$1.$ Let $b$ be in $X$. Then $b-b$ is in $X$. So $0$ is in $X$.

$2.$ Because $0$ is in $X$, for any $b$ in $X$ we have $0-b$ is in $X$. So $-b$ is in $X$.

$3.$ For any $a$ and $b$ in $X$, $a+b=a-(-b)$, so by $(2)$, $a+b$ is in $X$.

Answer (score 3):

In the fifth line I think that you meant to have $(b-b)-b\in X$; otherwise the argument’s fine. The empty set is vacuously closed under addition: there is no counterexample to the statement that **if** $x,y\in\varnothing$, then $x+y\in\varnothing$, simply because the antecedent is never true.

Answer (score 1):

Any statement of the form $\forall x(x\in A\rightarrow\varphi(x))$ is vacuously true if $A$ is empty.

In this case we have the statement $\forall x(x\in A\rightarrow(\forall y(y\in A\rightarrow x+y\in A)))$, for every $x$ and $y$ in $A$ their sum is in $A$. As the above says, this is automatically true when $A=\varnothing$ because $x\in\varnothing$ is false and the implication is therefore true.

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem:** Let $\varnothing \subsetneq A \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ be closed under subtraction. Then it is also closed under addition.

**Proof:** We will show that: $a \in A \Longrightarrow (-a)\in A$.

By $A$ being nonempty then exists some $n \in A$.

By $A$ being closed under subtraction $(n - n) \in A$. That is, $0 \in A$.

Considering $n \in A$ we have that by $A$ being closed under subtraction $(0 - n) \in A$. That is, $-n \in A$.

Hence: $a \in A \Longrightarrow (-a)\in A$

Now considering $n, m \in A$ we have that $-m \in A$ and by $A$ being closed under subtraction $(n - (-m)) \in A$. That is, $(n + m) \in A$.

$\blacksquare$

For $A = \varnothing$ we consider the conditional:

$n, m \in A \Longrightarrow (n+m) \in A$.

Because the antecedent is false (that's the part: $n, m \in A$) the entire statement is always true.

For more information on how to find the truth value of a conditional read [this].[1](http://www.regentsprep.org/Regents/math/geometry/GP1/ifthen.htm)